# "Как посуху / аки посуху" — фразеологизм или сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, фразеология, как, сравнительный-оборот

В примерах Нац. корпуса запятая чаще ставится в таком выражении: *ходить по воде, **как посуху***, реже — в таком: *ходить по воде **аки посуху***.

Чем же является "как посуху" и какова правильная пунктуация?

Comment: А разве это не опечатка?

Comment: Я все исправил: евернул первоночальный вариант.

Comment: @Юлия Мне кажется, что Вы противоречите сами себе. Говорите: ЗАПЯТАЯ чаще ставится в таком выражении: ходить по воде, как посуху, реже — в таком: ходить по воде аки посуху. А саму запятую изничтожаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, запятая не нужна.

**В Энциклопедическом словаре крылатых слов и выражений. — М.: «Локид-Пресс». (Вадим Серов. 2003.)** этот фазеологизм дается без запятой. То же и в **Большой толково-фразеологическом словаре Михельсона (оригинальная орфография).**

**По морю аки по суху. Ср. Мы ѣхали, какъ говорится, по морю аки по суху,** и нѣсколько разъ тонули при переправахъ черезъ рѣки по льду. Н. Макаровъ. Воспоминанія.

Из Библии (церковнославянский текст). В Новом Завете сказано: «Верою **перейдешь Красное море аки по суху».**

Comment: Вы говорите только про второй фразеологизм? Насчёт первого, меня смущает, что "по морю, как по суху" с запятой встречается во вполне нормальных изданиях в самые разные годы.

Comment: @grizzly Как Вы считаете, а моя правка НЕ исказила суть вопроса?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо за доверие, но позвольте пока мне у Вас учиться :)  (Я думаю, что не исказила.)